# Dynamic homepage with PHP - making things too complicated?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to show the 6 most popular products on my homepage from left to right, in two rows. My code actually works... but I have the feeling I am making things way too complicated. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY popularity DESC LIMIT 6");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); //Count the output amount
if($productCount>0){
    $currentRow=0;
    $dynamicListLeft='<div id="homepageLeftProduct">';
    $dynamicListMiddle='<div id="homepageMiddleProduct">';
    $dynamicListRight='<div id="homepageRightProduct">';
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $currentRow=$currentRow+1;
            $id = $row["id"];
            $product_name = $row["product_name"];
            $date_added=strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));

            if($currentRow==1 || $currentRow==4) {
                $dynamicListLeft .='<p>
        <a href="product.php?blablabla"><img class="homepagePic" src="inventory_images/4.jpg" /></a>
        </p><br/>';
            } else {
                    if($currentRow==2 || $currentRow==5) {
                        $dynamicListMiddle .='<p>
        <a href="product.php?blablabla"><img class="homepagePic" src="inventory_images/4.jpg" /></a>
        </p><br/>';
                    } else {
                            if($currentRow==3 || $currentRow==6){
                                $dynamicListRight .='<p>
        <a href="product.php?blablabla"><img class="homepagePic" src="inventory_images/4.jpg" /></a>
        </p><br/>';
                            }
                        }
                }

        }
        $dynamicListLeft .='</div>';
        $dynamicListMiddle .='</div>';              
        $dynamicListRight .='</div>';
        $dynamicList .=$dynamicListLeft;
        $dynamicList .=$dynamicListMiddle;
        $dynamicList .=$dynamicListRight;

}
```

Later on in my body I echo the dynamiclist.

I hope somebody can show me the way to make this smoother?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let's go for a step-by-step cleanup.

1) Get rid of repetition by using a variable to store your html code common to the different branches.

2) Remove useless levels of indentation to make things easier to follow.

The inside of the `while` loop is now :

```
        $currentRow=$currentRow+1;
        $id = $row["id"];
        $product_name = $row["product_name"];
        $date_added=strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
        $link = '<p><a href="product.php?blablabla"><img class="homepagePic" src="inventory_images/4.jpg" /></a></p><br/>';
        if($currentRow==1 || $currentRow==4) {
            $dynamicListLeft .= $link;
        } else if($currentRow==2 || $currentRow==5) {
            $dynamicListMiddle .= $link;
        } else if($currentRow==3 || $currentRow==6){
            $dynamicListRight .= $link';
        }
```

(I could move the definition of link out of the loop but I guess in your real situation, the content depends on `$row`).

3) You can try to store your content in an array instead of using different variables. It removes a bit of logic and makes things easier to update if you want 2 or 4 columns in the future. It also removes some code duplication :

```
$cols=array('','','');
$nbCol=count($cols);
$currentRow=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id = $row["id"];
        $product_name = $row["product_name"];
        $date_added=strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
        $link = '<p><a href="product.php?blablabla"><img class="homepagePic" src="inventory_images/4.jpg" /></a></p><br/>';
        $cols[$currentRow%$nbCol] .= $link;
        $currentRow=$currentRow+1;
}
for ($col as $i => $content)
{
   $dynamicList .= '<div id="homepageProductCol' . $i . '">' . $content . '</div>';
}
```

4) So far, the comments were about the php code and not the HTML output it produces. My last comment is more of a question but wouldn't there be a way to have your HTML defined in such a way that you don't need such a complicated logic. Basically, at the moment, the whole point is that your HTML code contains reference to your item in this order : 1,4,2,5,3,6. Things would be easier if you could have them in the natural order (1,2,3,4,5,6) in your HTML code and then update your HTML to display them in such a such a way.
My HTML skills are way too limited to answer this question...